# Accessing particular element in JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to filter out one particular element out of a json file using Python3.

This is what I have tried:

```
#Fetch rain radar (forecast) imagery
url_rain_forecast = 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/layer/wxfcs/all/json/capabilities?key=key'
response_rain_forecast = requests.get(url_rain_forecast, headers=headers, timeout = 60)
print(response_rain_forecast)
rain_forecast = response_rain_forecast.json()
response_rain_forecast.json()
```

Which gives a healthy response and the json structure:

```
<Response [200]>

{'Layers': {'@type': 'Forecast',
  'BaseUrl': {'@forServiceTimeFormat': 'Timesteps',
   '$': 'http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/layer/wxfcs/{LayerName}/{ImageFormat}?RUN={DefaultTime}Z&FORECAST={Timestep}&key={key}'},
  'Layer': [{'@displayName': 'Rainfall',
    'Service': {'@name': 'UKPPBEST',
     'LayerName': 'Precipitation_Rate',
     'ImageFormat': 'png',
     'Timesteps': {'@defaultTime': '2023-09-18T09:00:00',
      'Timestep': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36]}}},
   {'@displayName': 'Cloud',
    'Service': {'@name': 'UKPPBEST',
     'LayerName': 'Total_Cloud_Cover',
     'ImageFormat': 'png',
     'Timesteps': {'@defaultTime': '2023-09-18T09:00:00',
      'Timestep': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36]}}},
   {'@displayName': 'CloudAndRain',
    'Service': {'@name': 'UKPPBEST',
     'LayerName': 'Total_Cloud_Cover_Precip_Rate_Overlaid',
     'ImageFormat': 'png',
     'Timesteps': {'@defaultTime': '2023-09-18T09:00:00',
      'Timestep': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36]}}},
   {'@displayName': 'Temperature',
    'Service': {'@name': 'UKPPBEST',
     'LayerName': 'Temperature',
     'ImageFormat': 'png',
     'Timesteps': {'@defaultTime': '2023-09-18T09:00:00',
      'Timestep': [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36]}}},
   {'@displayName': 'Pressure',
    'Service': {'@name': 'FRONTS',
     'LayerName': 'Atlantic',
     'ImageFormat': 'png',
     'Timesteps': {'@defaultTime': '2023-09-18T00:00:00',
      'Timestep': [0, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72]}}}]}}
```

I want to extract the date `'Timesteps': {'@defaultTime': '2023-09-18T09:00:00'`, which I have tried using the below.

```
default_time = rain_forecast.get('Layers').get('Layer')[0].get('Timesteps')
print(default_time)
```

But that gives me a `None` result.

I think I am getting thrown off by the mix of different data? Would greatly appreciate any input.

Comment: You left out `Service` in your path. `rain_forecast['Layers']['Layer'][0]['Service']['Timesteps']['@defaultTime']` gives `'2023-09-18T09:00:00'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a solution like the following.

```
layers = rain_forecast.get('Layers').get('Layer')

for layer in layers:
    default_time = layer.get('Service').get('Timesteps').get('@defaultTime')
    print(default_time)
```

See that in this case it will return all the values that are in **Timesteps**

If you need a specific position, use this (just change list position):

```
layers = rain_forecast.get('Layers').get('Layer')
default_time = layers[0].get('Service').get('Timesteps').get('@defaultTime')
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!
I've tried your approach in a similar way but without splitting it like you did. As mentioned in the comment to Daviid's answer, I got an error message when simply adding `.get('@defaultTime')`.
Is that because of splitting/not splitting the path?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get `Timestep` from

```json
{
        "@displayName": "Rainfall",
        "Service": {
          "@name": "UKPPBEST",
          "LayerName": "Precipitation_Rate",
          "ImageFormat": "png",
          "Timesteps": {
            "@defaultTime": "2023-09-18T09:00:00",
            "Timestep": [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36]
          }
        }
      }
```

Which, with correct formatting, is obvious why doesn't work.

Update:
You're not paying enough attention, as you can see, @defaultTime is inside Timesteps, which is inside Service.
So, after [0] you need to select Service->Timesteps->@defaultTime

`[0].get('Service').get('Timesteps').get('@defaultTime')`

Comment: I am trying to get the ISO8601 date, which I had assumed would be `Timesteps` (with an `s`). 
Is my current path to get to `Timesteps` correct? When adding `.get('@defaultTime')` to path, I get an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`. Similar for adding `[0]` to my path: `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`
I appreciate the opportunity to learn, but I am still quite stuck.

Comment: Timesteps is inside of Service, so you need to select that first.